# How to delegate only the events from the active view in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have two views in Backbone. Register view and login view.

Login view

```
define(['text!templates/login.html'], function(loginTemplate) {
var loginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#content'),

    events: {
        "submit form": "login"
    },

    login: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/user/login', {
                email: $('input.login-email').val(),
                password: $('input.login-password').val()
            }, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }).error(function(){
                $("#error").text('Unable to login.');
                $("#error").slideDown();
            });
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(loginTemplate);
    }
});

return new loginView;
});
```

Register view

```
define(['text!templates/register.html'], function(registerTemplate) {
var registerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#content'),

    events: {
        "submit form": "register"
    },

    register: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/user/register', {
            emailaddress: $("input.email").val(),
            password: $("input.password").val()
        }, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(registerTemplate);
        this.delegateEvents();
    }
});

return new registerView;
});
```

And I undelegate the events from the currentView before switching in another. But the backbone view model calls the delegateEvent() function in its constructor. So, when I open the page in the browser and get the login view, and want to submit the form, there are two request, because the events from both views are delegated. Can I prevent the delegateEvent function in the constructor? I know, that I can use IDs and I will, but I don't like the 'mess' I want only the events from active views.

Thanks a lot.

Edit: here is my router, maybe it is the source of my "bug".

```
define(['views/register', 'views/login'], function(RegisterView, LoginView) {
var TestRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    currentView: null,
    routes: {
        "login": "login",
        "register": "register"
    },

    changeView: function(view) {
        if ( this.currentView != null ) {
            this.currentView.undelegateEvents();
        }
        this.currentView = view;
        this.currentView.render();
    },

    login: function() {
        this.changeView(LoginView);
    },

    register: function() {
        this.changeView(RegisterView);
    }
});

return new TestRouter;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're declaring the `el` property manually (`el: $('#content')`).

In clean code, you don't want to do this. Instead, you want to manage where the view is inserted dynamically in the router or in the parent view. Like so:

```
var view = new registerView();
view.render().$el.appendTo("#content");
```

It is very important to separate the layout from the views to keep your code maintainable and not falling on the issue you have here.

Comment: Yes, this is a good suggestion. But why does this affect the delegation of events at the construction of the views? The views would get constructed anyway at boot strap, wouldnt they?

Comment: Yes, but the delegation would happen on their internal wrapper `el` (which is specific to the context), not on `#content` (which is generic to the page).

Comment: Note too, that generally, it's more than ok to construct views only when needed. No need to cache them for reusing later. Just trash and recreate when needed, your code will be way more maintainable and the performance hit is usually unseen.

Comment: But the I will have a div#content where I will render all "main-views" like the login-page, the register-page and so on. And they are named the same. Or would you have a wrapper for each view? Like div#content > div#login? I dont like redudant divs.

Comment: You'd just need an empty `div` inserted div#content. Just a note, you care about "clean" HTML only for the code you write and maintain. Dynamic HTML doesn't matter at all, it won't change anything in your life and will make your JS code more maintainable. "redundant" div realy isn't a matter you should care about.

Comment: So there is no possibility to get all views and call undelegateEvents on them, or prevent calling delegateEvents on construct and only on rendering? When it's true, I suggest, that your answer will be the best. Many thanks.

Comment: There's probably a way or a hack of some way, but that'll be dirty and make your code unmaintainable (or at the very least very hard to follow). You should take the Backbone best practice into consideration and simply work around your root problem here.

Comment: Now I propably see the solution. You are creating the view in the changeView. I am creating it with require js (return new registerView), when I return the registerView (without new) require wouldnt create the view. I will check it.

Comment: You should check the Backbone-Boilerplate project if you're using Require.js and Backbone. There's some demo projects related that you can use for inspiration. https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem is:

When you do not construct all views at injecting them per dependency, they were not constructed and werent delegating their events.

Change

```
return new registerView;
```

to

```
return registerView;
```

in your view. Please notice the comment of Simon Boudrias and do not declare the views element in it.